# Updating user password in parse.com

Tags: lua, parse-platform, coronasdk

I am trying to use parse module in Corona SDK. I can create a user and logging which provides me with a `sessionToken` string. Then I am trying the following code to update the password; however, I get this error message:

> mod_parse.lua511:User must be logged in first, sessionToken cannot be nil.

As mentioned, I already get a `sessionToken`. Shall I declare that somewhere in the following code. Also in the code below "759P2STsjN"is the user objectId from parse. I tried replacing it with username but no luck.

```
local function onUpdateUser( event )
  if not event.error then
    print( event.response.updatedAt )
  end
end

local dataTable = { ["password"] = "newpassword", }
parse:updateUser( "759P2STsjN", dataTable, onUpdateUser )
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems like the sessionToken is not being saved

Comment: not really. got disconnected from this topic. I think better to do this on the local machine and time it out after some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I did not update the session token. Parse module should automatically do that but didnt. sessionToken = event.response.sessionToken will do the job. One otehr thing to remember you should allow a few seconds so that the network response is obtained before updating the user data. When you login it takes some time to update session token in your code. Therefore, either your code should allow some time to obtain it or ask the user to respond.

```
local function onLoginUser( event )
  if not event.error then
    print( event.response.sessionToken )
    sessionTokenParse = event.response.sessionToken

      sessionToken = event.response.sessionToken

  end
end

parse:loginUser( { ["username"] = "Chri1", ["password"] = "stro1w" }, onLoginUser )
```